# Jquery datatables display image in one of the columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery data tables and getting the data from server using Ajax. Basically the data I am sending is about an `Order` and there are different types of orders.

What I am trying to achieve is send in the `Order type` along with the order data and on the client side display an image.

I have two main types, `Surplus` and `Deficit`. I have both images as my static content on the client side and from server I am able to get the data. I am not sure how to display it.

This is how I get data from server

```
$('#matchOrderedTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": TippNett.Api.Url + "Match/DataTable",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.token = authToken;
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Created" },
        { "data": "Amount" },
        { "data": "OrderOrg" },
        { "data": "OrderMatchedOrg" },
        { "data": "OrderLoc" },
        { "data": "OrderMatchLoc" },
    ]
});
```

and my View looks like this

```
<table id="matchOrderedTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Texts.Created</th>
            <th>@Texts.Amount</th>
            <th>@Texts.Organizations</th>
            <th>@Texts.MatchedOrg</th>
            <th>@Texts.Locations</th>
            <th>@Texts.MatchedLoc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Any ideas or examples on how to do that?

Comment: does order type get returned with your grid data?

Comment: yes it does send it with the grid data.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the order type for each row so you can then use JavaScript to determine what image to display in the column?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing. But not sure how to manipulate it on client end.

Comment: Good, I was getting confused because you were saying send. Anyway you will need to use the `render` property in your column and return a string representation of the `<img />` tag. I will provide an example as an answer and hopefully can get it working from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property so that you can create a custom function to do your logic for checking the order type and then return the correct string representation of your image.

**Example (updated to match comment below)**

In your table declaration code add a column for the order type

```
$('#matchOrderedTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": TippNett.Api.Url + "Match/DataTable",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.token = authToken;
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Created" },
        { "data": "Amount" },
        { "data": "OrderOrg" },
        { "data": "OrderMatchedOrg" },
        { "data": "OrderLoc", render: getImg },
        { "data": "OrderMatchLoc", render: getImg }
    ]
});
```

Column render function code. The `data` property stores the row data as an object so use that to access the order type value.

UPDATE: even though there is no column for `OrderType` you can still access the object's value in the `data` param.

```
function getImg(data, type, full, meta) {
        var orderType = data.OrderType;
        if (orderType === 'Surplus') {
            return '<img src="image path here" />';
        } else {
            return '<img src="image path here" />';
        }
    }
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the solution. I tried and it is working. The only issue is that I don't want a separate column for Order Type. I want to concatenate it with the OrderLoc and OrderMatchLoc.

Comment: I'll update my answer to remove the `OrderType` column then, let me know if its correct and works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add image this way:

```
$('#matchOrderedTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": TippNett.Api.Url + "Match/DataTable",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.token = authToken;
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Created" },
        { "data": "Amount" },
        { "data": "OrderOrg" },
        { "data": "OrderMatchedOrg" },
        { data: 'OrderLoc',render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<img src="' + data + '" height="50" width="50"/>';
              }
            },
        { "data": "OrderMatchLoc", render: getImg }
    ]
});
```