# How to display image in datatable?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I want to show an image in my datatable.The data to be displayed in the datatable is a json array of arrays like this:

```
data : [["1", "John","image1.jpg"], ["2", "Jim", "image2.jpg"]]
```

So in my database I only have the name of the image and I don't know how to display the image itself.

Comment: Hi, you can refer this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32924/is-it-possible-to-show-image-in-datatable 
and this https://jsfiddle.net/glenderson/yg1w6gen/1/

Answer (score 6):

It has been asked before, but not with a simple array of arrays datasrc. Use `columnDefs` to target the index of the image, use `render` to construct the `<img>` tag :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: 2,
      render: function(data) {
        return '<img src="'+data+'">'
      }
    }   
  ]
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/965/** See also

[View pictures or images inside Jquery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206419/view-pictures-or-images-inside-jquery-datatable)
[Jquery datatables display image in one of the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942662/jquery-datatables-display-image-in-one-of-the-columns)
[Displaying image on Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152698/displaying-image-on-datatable)

Answer (score 1):

An experience I had was how to print, then I found the **stripHtml: false** as below

```
    "buttons": [
        {
            extend: 'print',
            title: 'nono nonono',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible',
                stripHtml: false,
            },
            text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body)
                    .css('font-size', '10pt')
                    .prepend(
                        '<img src="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                    );

                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                    .addClass('compact')
                    .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        },
    ]
```